# Why URI-encoded ('#') anchors cause 404, and how to deal with it in JS?

Tags: javascript, hash, webkit, hashtag

[prettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) utilizes hashtags, but if they get encoded (to %23), most browsers will bring up a 404 error. This [has been discussed before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3784983):

> You get a 404 error because the #callback part is not part of the URL.
>   It's a bookmark that is used by the browser, and it's never sent in
>   the request to the server. If you encode the hash, it becomes part of
>   the file name instead.

1. Why would a hash become part of the file just because it's URI-encoded? Isn't it a bug?
2. I'm asking because [prettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) uses hashtags and suffers from the same issue. I think adding a '?' before the hash is the most elegant solution, I'm just at a bit of a loss how to do it in the existing code:

   ```
   function getHashtag(){
   url=location.href;
   hashtag=url.indexOf('#gallery')!==-1)?decodeURI(url.substring(url.indexOf('#gallery')+1,url.length)):false;
   return hashtag;
   }
   function setHashtag(){
   if(typeof theRel=='undefined')return; location.hash=theRel+'/'+rel_index+'/';
   }
   function clearHashtag(){
   if(location.href.indexOf('#gallery')!==-1)location.hash="";
   }
   ```
3. Any other suggestions? I'll look into tweaking my 404 page, but that seems more like handling a problem rather than preventing it.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**  Since evidently there's nothing wrong with the way prettyphoto handles those hashes, I ended up adding these rules to my apache server:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).shtml(%23|#)$ /$1.shtml [R=301,NE,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*).shtml([^g]+)gallery(.+)$ /$1.shtml#gallery$3 [R=301,NE,L]
```

They successfully handle the cases where %23 caused issues.

Comment: to incorporate the ? into the code above it looks like you can modify the 'url' var that has been defined to read url=location.href+'?'

Comment: Also note that the SO question tag 'hash' is explicitly referring to hash algorithms. The URL/HTML feature is better classified under 'anchor'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 1. Why would a hash become part of the file just because it's URI-encoded? Isn't it a bug?

If you point your browser to `http://example.com/index.html#title`, the browser interprets this to make a request for the file `index.html` from the server `example.com`. Once the request is complete, the browser looks for an anchor element in the document with the name of 'title' (i.e. `<a name="title">My title</a>`).

If you instead point to `http://example.com/index.html%23title`, the browser makes a request for the file `index.html%23title` from `example.com`, which probably doesn't exist on the server, giving you a 404. See the difference?

And it's not a bug. It's part of an internet standard [last updated](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) in 1998. See [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt). Quoting:

> The character "#" is excluded because it is used to delimit a URI from a fragment identifier in URI references (Section 4).

As for 2 and 3, there's not enough context in your example code to tell what you're trying to do. How are you calling your code? What are you trying to do with prettyphoto that isn't working? Are you trying to redirect to a specific photo or gallery from a user click or other javascript event? Are you trying to open the gallery when someone visits a particular page?

I checked the linked question with twitter/oauth, but I don't see how that ties into the code you provided. I started poking at prettyphoto as well, but I don't see how your code relates to that either.

Instead of changing your 404 page, maybe what you need is an in-code handler or server rewrite rule that takes not-found requests with a `%23` in them and redirects the user to the decoded url. That could have some drawbacks, but it would be fairly elegant if you're taking incoming requests from other sources you can't control. What is your server environment? (language, server tech, who owns the machine, etc.)

I'd be happy to update my answer with a solution or a work around for you.

Comment: Thanks, everyone! My issue was originally caused by end users using an encoded version of the link and getting a 404. I'm not even sure how it got encoded, could be trips through Gmail and Earthlink email programs. For that reason, I wonder if the "?" approach is no good since that could get URIencoded too.

Comment: As for RFC 2396, I wonder why the browser doesn't decode %23 before sending the URL over, then?

Comment: As you said, the link had probably been encoded before the user ever saw it. Browsers don't decode links because they have no way of knowing the intent of whoever wrote it. If I were to actually name a news article 'Who ate the last cookie?', and you accessed it by going to `http://example.com/Who+ate+the+last+cookie%3F`, if your browser decoded it, it would interpret the decoded ? as the start of a query string and you would get a 404. (Actually, probably not for ?, but that was a more realistic example than the url I thought up for #.)

Comment: And as for fixing the problem of people getting bad links, it sounds like you would need to implement something at the server level. In apache, you could get this done with rewrite rules: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html I'm sure there are equivalents methods for other servers, but I've not used them. Post your server environment and someone might be able to help you out.

Comment: I looked into mod_write, I'm running my own VPS with Apache 2 so I've got full control. Just need help with the regex pattern - I was trying to pass the string up until the first occurrence of %23.

Answer (score 2):

To answer #1)

It would become a part of the URL because it's no longer a token which the browser/server/etc know how to parse out.

What I mean is that "?" plays a significant role in URLs -- the server knows to separate what's before from what's after.
The browser doesn't need to care about what is or isn't dynamic in the URI - it's all significant (though JavaScript separates the values in the location object).

The browser won't send "#......" to the server, as the hashtag has special connotations for the browser.

However, if you escape that hash in JavaScript, the browser won't hesitate to send that escaped string to the server as a literal value.

Why wouldn't it?  If your search query legitimately required a hash character (you make a POST request to a facebook wall, and you're submitting a phonenumber), then you'd be screwed.
Or you're doing a GET-based search of some number on 411.com or whatever, and they haven't really thought their application through.

The problem is that the server isn't going to understand that the escaped value is to be held separately from the url, if it's occurring in the actual path.

It has to accept escaped characters, otherwise spaces (%20) and other every-day characters, which are otherwise valid in filenames/paths/queries/values would pose problems.

So if you're looking for:

```
//mysite.gov.on.ca/path/to/file.extension%23action%3Dfullscreen
```

verily, you shall surely 404.

There are a few things that you could do, I'm certain.
The first would be in Apache, or whatever you're serving from, you could write a RegEx which matches any url up to the first "%23", assuming that there is no "?" beforehand.

Less soul-rending implementations might involve figuring out if there's a way to escape the "#" that are plug-in friendly.

Google, for-instance, uses a "hash-bang" strategy ("#!") where it asks that URLs be submitted that way, to know whether or not to encode.

Other options might be to check for a "#" character using `url.indexOf("#");` and splitting the URL at the hash, and submitting the valid portion.

It really all comes down to what you're trying to accomplish -- I can point at why it's an issue, but the how to best make it a non-issue relies on what you're trying to do, how you're trying to do it, and what's allowed in the context you're working in.