# Issue in android:pathPrefix on AndroidManifest.xml with special character #

Tags: android, nativescript, android-manifest, nativescript-angular

I have the following link:
https://thus.customapp.it/#/app/customapp/itemDetail/45289348293423

I want that this link is captured and opened with my app. So, I added these lines on AndroidManifest file:

```
<intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
       <data android:scheme="https" android:host="thus.customapp.it" android:pathPrefix="/#/app/customapp/itemDetail"/>
</intent-filter>
```

I also tried with:

```
<data android:scheme="https" android:host="thus.customapp.it" android:pathPrefix="/#/app/customapp/itemDetail/.*"/>
```

and this:

```
 <data android:scheme="https" android:host="thus.customapp.it" android:pathPattern="/.*/.*/.*/.*/..*"/>
```

and this:

```
  <data android:scheme="https" android:host="thus.customapp.it" android:android:pathPrefix="/#"/>
```

and this:

```
<data android:scheme="https" android:host="thus.customapp.it" android:pathPattern="/#/.*" />
```

but it doesn't work.

P.S. with the following code:

```
<data android:scheme="https" android:host="thus.customapp.it" android:pathPattern="/.*"/>
```

it works, but I need to intercept just a url which contains "itemDetail", and not, for example, https://thus.customapp.it/#/app/customapp/editItem/45289348293423

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: No error, but If i tap the link it opens with Chrome and not with the app

Comment: Have you checked for a simple link?

Comment: @GOVINDDIXIT I edited my question, maybe it can helps

Comment: try using android:path="/#/app/customapp/editItem/45289348293423" instead of android:pathPattern="/.*"

Comment: the last '45289348293423' is an ID, should I use android:path="/#/app/customapp/itemDetail/..* " ?

Comment: Yes go with using android:path="/#/app/customapp/itemDetail/..*

Comment: It doesn't work :/ could it be that the issue is coming from the # character? Maybe it is transformed into "%23" ?

Comment: I tried to hanlde the path with %23, so I built the url with '%23' instad of '#' and it works! But if I choose to open it with Chrome, it doesn't work because it doesn't decode %23 into [#

Comment: Happy to help. I have written all this in an answer for future reference. You can have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
android:path="/%23/app/customapp/itemDetail/.*
```

instead of

```
android:pathPrefix="/#/app/customapp/itemDetail/.*"
```

**Edit:** As suggested by @panagulis72 we should use %23 instead of #

Comment: Now the app intercepts the url, but I have the opposite problem now! Indeed if I choose to open the link the Chrome, it gives me 404 because the url with /%23/ doesn't exist, just /#/ exists

Comment: Let me know if this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587744/why-uri-encoded-anchors-cause-404-and-how-to-deal-with-it-in-js

Comment: I tried but it doesnt work, so I change the way and I built a redirect page on my web app, and I pass the parameters via query Parameters (even if the query parameters are ignored: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56970072/nativescript-urlhandler-doesnt-intercept-queryparams-in-android-deep-link). Anyway thank you very much for you help!